# javascript trunc() function

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to truncate a number in javascript, that means to cut away the decimal part:

**trunc ( 2.6 ) == 2**

**trunc (-2.6 ) == -2**

---

After heavy benchmarking my answer is:

```
 function trunc (n) {
    return ~~n;
 }
 
 // or  

 function trunc1 (n) {
    return n | 0;
 }
```

Comment: Note that bitwise methods (e.g., ~~n or n|0) only work on numbers up to 2^31-1, or 2147483647. 2147483648 or higher will return an incorrect result; for example, 2147483647|0 returns -2147483648, and 4294967295|0 returns -1, which is almost definitely not what you want

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As an addition to the [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125715/javascript-trunc-function/2125728#2125728)'s answer, if you want to truncate always towards zero, you can:

```
function truncate(n) {
  return n | 0; // bitwise operators convert operands to 32-bit integers
}
```

Or:

```
function truncate(n) {
  return Math[n > 0 ? "floor" : "ceil"](n);
}
```

Both will give you the right results for both, positive and negative numbers:

```
truncate(-3.25) == -3;
truncate(3.25) == 3;
```

Answer (score 13):

For positive numbers:

```
Math.floor(2.6) == 2;
```

For negative numbers:

```
Math.ceil(-2.6) == -2;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [toFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) method that also allows to specify the number of decimal numbers you want to show:

```
var num1 = new Number(3.141592);
var num2 = num1.toFixed(); // 3
var num3 = num1.toFixed(2); // 3.14
var num4 = num1.toFixed(10); // 3.1415920000
```

Just note that *toFixed* rounds the number:

```
var num1 = new Number(3.641592);
var num2 = num1.toFixed(); // 4
```

Comment: Rounding means that its not truncating. Also note that toFixed returns a string

Answer (score 4):

I use

```
function trunc(n){
   return n - n % 1;
}
```

because it works over the whole float range and should (not measured) be faster than

```
function trunc(n) {
  return Math[n > 0 ? "floor" : "ceil"](n);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Your way is only slightly faster, but it's much more compact, which also has an effect on performance.  Even better, I don't have to use a function call, I can just embed (n - n % 1) inline!  I've been using (n | 0), but that only works correctly for numbers below 32-bit sizes rather than the full 64-bit floating point range.  I'll be using this from now on, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case it wasn't available before and for anyone else who stumbles upon this thread, you can now simply use the trunc() function from the Math library, like so:

```
let x = -201;
x /= 10;
console.log(x);
console.log(Math.trunc(x));

>>> -20.1
>>> -20
```